# Push Notification to Specific Logged In User using Firebase/Batch

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I'm building an app that allows the user to create events and add people to those events. It stores the event and certain user data (email and display name) in a Firebase database.

What I'm trying to do is send a notification to a specific user when another user adds them to an event. I've tried looking at the documentation for both Firebase Notifications/Cloud Messaging and Batch, but I can't find a way to send the notification to a single user, rather than an entire group.

How do I go about doing this? I'm hoping to avoid storing the notification in the Firebase DB and setting up a servlet backend that queries the DB repeatedly.

Edit: If I do have to make a Java Servlet backend for this, can someone tell me how I would code it?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do that by specifying the device token when sending the notification using console or using post request to FCM server. But unfortunately you have to handle every single device token manually by yourself (get it from the device when it [register](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-device) to FCM, and save it to your own DB somewhere).

If you use console, you can put the token on "FCM registration token" field under target -> single device.

If you use post request, you can make a request like this

```
{
    "data": {"my_custom_key" : "my_custom_value"},
    "registration_ids": ["your-device-token","your-device2-token"]
}
```

Comment: I want the notification to be generated automatically upon the user being added to the event, rather than having to do it myself through console.

Comment: I think you have to implement the send notification message via GCM HTTP connection server protocol somewhere on your backend server. So it can be generated automatically by the backend whenever needed. See the detail here https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ . Just add the registration_ids (like I said above) to the post body.

Answer (score 0):

Batch.com provides a simpler API named [Transactional API](https://batch.com/doc/api/transactional.html) to **send a notification to one or more users** identified by their User ID, Firebase UID etc. as you probably don't want to deal with the complexity of APNS push tokens or GCM registration ids yourself. Contrary to FCM, you will get a complete analytics view (eg: open-rate) on those notifications.

You can trigger push notifications directly from your app code by using our [Swift client](https://gist.github.com/abarisain/91ff0812e65cfcb85b3a9195a0f76622) for the Transactional API or by coding your own HTTP client (it's a standard POST request with a JSON body). We even have a client for [Node.js](https://gist.github.com/abarisain/8f1747a2ed92c88ad7e5a027fb651f42) if you decide to trigger the notifications from a server.

And if you are using Firebase, we have a specific documentation to [plug Firebase with Batch](https://batch.com/firebase).